# ruby mechanize emulate js

Tags: javascript, ruby

I'm trying to scrape http://georgiafacts.org/manufacturers that uses some js.  My code fills in three field values, then posts the page.  It seems that I get the same screen back, so I must not understand what the js code is doing.

Here is the code for the button:

```
<a onclick="OnSubmit();" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSearch" title="Begin Search" class="gobutton" vspace="3" alternatetext="GO" href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSearch", "", true, "", "", false, true))'>GO</a>
```

Here is my little ruby program trying to get to the second page:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
require 'logger'
page = agent.get('http://georgiafacts.org/manufacturers/')
georgia_form = page.form
georgia_form.fields[4].value = "20"
georgia_form.fields[5].value = "20000"
georgia_form.fields[0].value = 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSearch'
master_page = agent.post(georgia_form)
pp master_page
```

So my question is, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If your submitted form values do not change, you generally should get the same screen back, right?

Comment: I fetch the form, change 3 values, then submit the form.  I expect to get a list of manufacturers who meet the criterion.

Comment: Found the problem.

master_page = agent.submit(georgia_form)   # not post but submit...